# Toast is not working inside Fragemet

Tags: android, android-fragments, toast

i have one fragment and  MainActivity.Fragment is called inside the Main Activity.in fragment i put Toast (in test purpose of ImageView).the toast there isn't working.please find below the code i used.

```
   package com.maintab;
import com.example.tesfragement.R;
import com.example.tesfragement.R.layout;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class Login extends Fragment   {

    View view;
    ImageView loginbuttton,logoutbutton;


    public Login() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.login, container, false);
        loginbuttton=(ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.loinbutton);
        loginbuttton.setOnClickListener( btnClick);

        return view;
    }

    ImageView.OnClickListener btnClick=new ImageView.OnClickListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             if((v.getId()==loginbuttton.getId()))
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"hello", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }

        }

    };

}
```

Comment: is it `loinbutton` or `loginbutton`??

Comment: have you tried after changing `if(v==loginbuttton)` to `if(v.getId()==loginbuttton.getId())` ? because `ImageView !=View` both is different class

Comment: Try comparing `View's` id as they are identifier for views.

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK tried but no chage

Comment: implements `onClickListner` to your `Fragment` and `override onClick() event`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this..

Change `v == loginbuttton` to `v.getId() == R.id.loinbutton`

```
   @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(v.getId() == R.id.loinbutton)
        {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"hello", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
```

**EDIT:**

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.login, container, false);
    loginbuttton=(ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.loinbutton);
    loginbuttton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"hello", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    });

    return view;
}
```

Comment: @RehanK So there is some other problem. Because in your code also no issue. You have to just check ImageView id or any other issue.

Comment: @Piyush Gupta there wasn't any problem with ImageView id

Comment: @RehanK I have tested your code also. There was no issue with that.

Comment: @PiyushGupta you all correct I'm having problem with intial loading screen i have to paste my code there also the  its works.thank you all

Comment: @Hariharan But I think there is no problem with `v == loginbuttton` as same instance is passed to `onClick()` method and we can use `==` operator for reference comparison...

Answer (score 1):

`==` compares object references, it checks to see if the two operands point to the same object.

In this line

```
if(v==loginbuttton)
```

change into

```
if(v.getId()==loginbuttton.getId())
```

Comment: i cant remove onlick i have to implement unimplemeted metthods here i want to take a button working somehow inside the frgement.

Comment: @RehanK are you understand..i am not saying remove onclick i am saying remove if condtion and diaplay toast for testing..

Comment: im sorry now i did it my onclick also not working.please help me.

Comment: is your fragmnet attached to your activity

Comment: i think it was the Error i got how i add myFragement to My activity please help me.

Comment: @ kalyan pvs i have posted my edited code.please find above i used.thnnk you.

Comment: @kalyanpvs But I think there is no problem with `v == loginbuttton` as same instance is passed to `onClick()` method and we can use `==` operator for reference comparison...

Comment: @GopalRao yes you are right..i am tested..during the conversation with op here the problem is not the click listener its due to Fragment attachment to the Activity..

Answer (score 0):

this answer may helps you :)

```
public class Login extends Fragment implements OnClickListener {


View view;
private ImageView loginbuttton;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.login, container, false);
    loginbuttton = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.loginbutton);

    return view;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    loginbuttton.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.loginbutton:
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "login", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        break;

      //    case R.id.logoutbutton:
      //            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "logout", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      //    break;

    default:
        break;
    }

}

}
```